# JSON.stringify large objects for store-like purpose

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I got state Observable like this :

The most important here is this line : `map((action: any) => JSON.stringify(action)),`
The action: any is just  **object which contains all ngrx store properties**, that depening on application may be little or verry large. So sometmies it contains object that is just  too large for JSON.stringify and I got invalid string length error.

I need something that will iterate deep into every object and call JSON.stringify for the most deep object so it will not run for entire action object because it will always crash due to having to large object...

```
 public state$: Observable<string | null> = this.store$.pipe(
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument
    map((action: any) => JSON.stringify(action)),
    tap((state: string) => {
      if (this.last5State.length > 5) {
        this.last5State.shift();
      }

      this.last5State = [...(this.last5State as string[]), state];
    }),
    catchError((err: unknown) => {
      console.error(err);
      return of(null);
    })
  );
```

EDIT: I've implemented function that is recursive and is supposed to run JSON.stringify fot every nested object... It seems like it almost working, but it still crashes with [image]

```
  private storeString = '';

  private iterateStore(storeObject: any) {
    Object.keys(storeObject).forEach((key) => {
      if (typeof storeObject[key] === 'object' && storeObject[key] !== null) {
        this.iterateStore(storeObject[key]);
        this.storeString += JSON.stringify(storeObject[key]);
      }
    });
```

Comment: What is your aim here? Debugging or something else?

Comment: yes, we have our own debug-window instead of redux devtools extension, and the value of this Observable goes there, but as I said, Json.stringify cannot handle too big obejcts sometimes